# Django extension job run daily

Tags: python, django, django-extensions

I'm trying to implement django extension management job. I would like to know how could I fire the job inside django in order to run the code daily and specify exact time like 4:00 am in django extension management job. so far code given below:

```
from django_extensions.management.jobs import DailyJob

class Job(DailyJob):
    help = "Send notification On Instruction Instances"

      
    def execute(self):
        print("job executed at 4:00 Am")
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Django doesn't handle the timing, crontab does.

As long as you're ok with *all* daily jobs running at 4am you can just update your crontab to use that. The [docs](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jobs_scheduling.html) show:

```
@daily /path/to/my/project/manage.py runjobs daily
```

And [these docs](http://ss64.com/osx/crontab.html) show that `@daily` is equivalent to `0 0 * * *`.

So just change your crontab to:

```
0 4 * * * /path/to/my/project/manage.py runjobs daily
```

Their [source code](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/main/django_extensions/management/commands/runjob.py) also shows there is a `runjob` command which can take a job name. So to run *just* that job at 4am, you would use:

```
0 4 * * * /path/to/my/project/manage.py runjob my_job
```

However, this job must *not* be a DailyJob then, since it would run twice (once daily from `runjobs daily`, once at 4am from `runjob myjob`). I think to do this, you would just inherit from `BaseJob` instead:

```
class Job(BaseJob):
    help = "Send notification On Instruction Instances"
```

But I am not 100% sure where this would go in your code. I'd probably start by trying to add it directly under the `jobs/` directory.

Comment: Thanks @Jamie for detailed instructions. really helpful. i got my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is correct, but just to add a few more options for you, there are django packages that handle background tasks and scheduling quite nicely, ranging from simple stuff that just kicks of a task when you want, to complex solutions like celery.

Check out https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/workers-queues-tasks/ for a full list of packages you may find useful here.

Comment: yes @michjnich absolutely, also got help from the link given by you for queuing tasks in django